Trying to configure the network connection in Open Indiana virtualized with bhyve on FreeBSD 14.1
I've just virtualized Open Indiana in bhyve (FreeBSD hypervisor),using the following parameters :
bhyve-win -S -c sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2 -m 4G -w -H -A \
-s 0,hostbridge \
-s 1,ahci-hd,/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/bhyve/img/Open-Indiana/efi/Minimal/openindiana-1.img \
-s 8:0,passthru,2/0/0 \
-s 8:1,passthru,2/0/1 \
-s 8:2,passthru,2/0/2 \
-s 8:3,passthru,2/0/3 \
-s 13,virtio-net,tap5 \
-s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5905,w=1600,h=950,wait \
-s 31,lpc \
-l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_UEFI_CODE.fd \
vm0:5 < /dev/null & sleep 2 && vncviewer 0:5 &

As you can see I've installed the minimal ISO image because for some unknown reasons,the full installation is not able to finish correctly. I've repeated it several times,but reached the last option to configure, I get bounced back to the beginning.
You can also see that between the bhyve parameters I'm using virtio-net. The problem that I have is that the network is not configured inside the vm,I don't have an active connection.
At this point,I've tried to use configure Open Indiana using qemu instead of bhyve,using the following parameters :
qemu-system-x86_64 -name guest=s11x64,debug-threads=on \
  -machine pc,usb=off \
  -cpu kvm64,hv_relaxed,hv_time,hv_synic \
  -m 8G -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 \
  -nodefaults -no-shutdown \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=/usr/local/share/edk2-qemu/QEMU_UEFI_CODE-x86_64.fd \
  -drive file=/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/bhyve/img/Open-Indiana/efi/Minimal/openindiana-1.img,format=raw \
  -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 \
  -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 \
  -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x7 \
  -device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x4 \
  -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x1 \
  -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x2 \
  -device VGA,id=video0,vgamem_mb=32,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \
  -netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap4,script=no,downscript=no \
  -device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \
  -device ich9-ahci,id=sata

In this case I'm not using the virtio drivers,but the e1000 network interface and also in this case I'm not able to establish the internet connection inside the vm.
I've tried to follow this tutorial :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59668_01/html/E59667/z40001c91004844.html
but it didn't work :

I've also tried to configure the network inside Open Indiana virtualized with bhyve,following this thread :
Changing the IP Address in Solaris 11
but it didn't work even in this case. Something is missing :

Can some one help me to configure correctly the network inside the OS ? I never used Open Indiana,but I'm curious to try it a little bit.
The result of command:
# netstat -rn 

is :


Did you set proper default gateway, DNS?

I've created this /etc/resolv.conf file :
search homenet.telecomitalia.it
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0
nameserver 8.8.8.8 ; but it does not work,I get the same error.

Please add in your question the result of command: netstat -rn

https://ibb.co/nrvC9Ld

You do not have default gateway. Set it and try again https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-change-the-default-route-or-gateway-on-solaris/

worked. very thanks bro.

If you like you may consider to accept my answer (the tick on the left the answer)

The problem is you do not have set default gateway. In Solaris you can do it via adding IP of gateway in /etc/defaultrouter and then restart the machine.
If you want temporary add it you can use command:
route add default 172.19.1.1

where 172.19.1.1 is the IP of your gateway
